# Best way to merge from another git repository

Tags: git, merge

Hi guys I'd like to hear your opinions. I have a situation we have migrated to git recently. After first migration and some development works have been done, We just notice that migration had went wrong. We re-created a new repository.

The problem here is commit hash is all different between repositories.

I would like to merge only our development works with full commit history from current master branch to new repository. What is the best option should I take? Simply if I add two remotes and merge, git creates whole new commits. patch? cherry-pick?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second remote ([`git remote add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)) to your old repo, fetch it, and [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) all the commits done in that old repo to your `master` branch of your new repo.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. I was doing opposite way. I added a second remote to my new repo on old repo. I could cherry-pick commits and pushed them to remote master but rejected. Why?

Comment: @KenichiTakemura probably (it depends on the rejection massage) because of a different history. By doing it in your new repo, you create that new history directly on the target branch: nothing to push, and it just works.